# How can I tell Ubuntu 18.04 to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?

Tags: suspend, power-management, lid

[Power Change options in dconf-editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2MoD.png)

I want my laptop to do nothing when I close the laptop lid. I found these options in dconf-editor for the laptop to do 'nothing'. However, the laptop still goes to suspended mode after I close the lid.

What did go wrong?

Answer (score 22):

Install **gnome-tweaks**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
```

and invoke it with

```
gnome-tweaks
```

Under the menu **Power** you can disable **Suspend when laptop lid is closed**.

Comment: This did not work for me. But this did work: https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/#prettyPhoto

Comment: It works, and the command to install gnome-tweaks is also right. But the application command to invoke it is not gnome-tweaks, it should be "Tweaks". My Ubuntu version is 18.04.